# C error dereferencing pointer to incomplete type linked list dic

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Hi guys I've had a look at the other questions with similar issues but couldn't find anything similar. I'm getting an error (as per title) in line 69 of my code and I'm not sure how to fix it. My code doesn't compile atm. This program is meant to take in keyvalue pairs and form a sorted dictionary linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
  int key;
  char value[256];
  struct node *next;
} node;

void findloc(int key, node*headnode);
void insert(node*newinserte, node*previous, node*after);

int main()
{
  makedic();
}

int makedic()
{
  int keydata, once;
  int compareval = 0;
  int i = 0;
  char valuedata[256];
  node * root, *head, *tmp;
  head = NULL;
  while (scanf("%d %s", &keydata, &valuedata) != EOF)
  {
    root = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->key = keydata;
    strcpy(root->value, value data);
    root->next = head;
    head = root;
    if (head != NULL && once == 0)
    {
      tmp = head;
      once++;
    }
    findloc(root->key, tmp);
  }
  /*for(; p1->next!=NULL;p1 = p1->next)
   {
   for (p2 = p1->next;p2!=NULL;p2=p2->next)
   {
   if(p1->key>p2->key)
   {
   int temp = p1 ->key;
   p1 ->key = p2->key;
   p2 ->key =temp;
   compareval = compareval +1;
   }
   }
   }*/
  //root = root -> next;  
  while (root)
  {
    printf("%d %s\n", root->key, root->value);
    root = root->next;
  }
  printf("%d\n", compareval);
}

void findloc(int keysearch, node*headnode)
{
  int i;
  node*head, *root;
  head = headnode;
  while (headnode->next != NULL )
  {
/*line 69*/    if (keysearch < headnode->next->key) //error is here
    {
      if (keysearch > headnode->key)
      {
        //insert(headnode ,headnode->next,headnode->next->next );
      }
    }
  }
}

void insert(node*newinserte, node*previous, node*after)
{
  int tmp = after;
  previous->next = newinserte;
  newinserte->next = tmp;
}
```

Comment: You're declaring a struct which can only be used to form the object at the declaration not anywhere else by no giving a name to the struct.

Comment: Btw: `int main()` ought to return an `int`. And do not cast `malloc/calloc/realloc` as in C it is not necessary nor recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Answer (score 1):

This

```
typedef struct
{
  int key;
  char value[256];
  struct node *next;
} node;
```

shall be this:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int key;
  char value[256];
  struct node * next;
} node;
```

Otherwise the member `struct node * next` would point to an unknown type, namely `struct node`.

---

Note: Although the former is perfectly valid, for the sake of reducing possible confusion I'd declare it the following way:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int key;
  char value[256];
  struct node * next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Typo in your answer:The member should be `struct node * next`